# Await/Async nodejs with mysql db won't giving result what is expected

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "anujsingh",
  database: "test",
});
con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
const selectCountries = async () => {
  let sql = "SELECT countries.* FROM countries";
  try {
    let result = await con.query(sql);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
selectCountries();
```

Attached screenshot of console, I am not getting what exactly I am getting, I want to call a function where I am consoling and send that data to a function which make insert queries based on that data.

[image]

Comment: What package are you using to connect to mysql? Because https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql doesn't seem to support promises. What you see, is the result of the `con.query()` function, which is a `Query` object, yet to be sent to server. See the docs on how to properly send the query to the server and retrieve the data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `con.query` in such a way as it returns a function with more than just results. You also do not need to call `con.connect()` - it is implicit with every `.query()`

The following should work for you. I've included additional functions to illustrate the async nature of the approach.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.NAME || 'local_database'
});


const do_thing_one = async (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    payload.one = 'thing one';
    resolve(payload)
  });
};

const selectCountries = async (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query('SELECT countries.* FROM countries', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      payload.countries = results
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });
};

const do_thing_three = async (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    payload.three = 'thing three'
    resolve(payload)
  });
};


const execute = async () => {
  let payload = {}
  await do_thing_one(payload)
  await selectCountries(payload)
  await do_thing_three(payload)
  console.log(payload);
}

execute();
```

**Will log…**

```
{
  one: 'thing one',
  countries: [
    RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'Brazil' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 2, name: 'China' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 3, name: 'Japan' }
  ],
  three: 'thing three'
}
```

Comment: What if the connection is not ready while you were execute ```selectCountries(payload)``` method ? Shouldn't your code first make sure if the connection is ready or not and then query ?

Comment: That is taken care of by the package. It will not run a query if it can not connect. And if the connection fails in that process for whatever reason, it would have failed for the same reason if you manually ran `.connect()` as well.